# Networking ARP table in windows cmd

Tags: windows, networking, internet, arp, windows-command-prompt

I am reading the book practical packet analysis and I have just learned the fundamentals of the ARP protocol. **They also added something about the arp -a cmd command. I'm curious about some of the extra addresses, and I can't find much information about them on the web.** I understand that FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF means broadcast to all. I'm also aware of the network address and host address combination of the IP address in dottedquad notation and understand the subnet mask.

Although I am still furiously curious about this ARP table. When I enter the commands arp -a This is the output of my CMD:

C:>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.4 --- 0xd

Internet Address       Physical Address      Type

192.168.1.1            a0-21-b7-b0-da-2f     dynamic

192.168.1.255          ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

224.0.0.22            01-00-5e-00-00-16     static

224.0.0.251           01-00-5e-00-00-fb     static

224.0.0.252           01-00-5e-00-00-fc     static

255.255.255.255       ff-ff-ff-ff-ff-ff     static

I am just curious about the last four connections of class D networks. Should these be here normally? Is my computer connecting to something other than the router with the ARP normally? I understand that ARP broadcasts itself to every computer on a network. I'm just curious about this ARP table because the book is lacking an explanation on this. I would love to understand the purpose behind the standard listing of these addresses in my ARP table.

As always please and thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's normal. Those addresses are in a reserved IP range for multicasting.  Multicast can be used by a lot of different things, but in general it's used for streaming data from a broadcast source to multiple clients.  Applications can include video streaming, VOIP, and a score of different network discovery protocols.

You can see more information on the addresses you noted here:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml#multicast-addresses-1

The ones you saw specifically:

- 224.0.0.22 - IGMP
- 224.0.0.251 - mDNS
- 224.0.0.252 - Link-local Multicast Name Resolution

`.22` is used for managing multicast memberships - multicast broadcasts are often in a "tree" structure, where members can be added/removed depending on if they need/want to be part of the multicast broadcast.

`.251` and `.252` are for helping your computer resolve names of other computers on your network.  You can read more details on implementation here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878128.aspx